# Alternative to SmartCardConnection in Windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, nfc, smartcard

I'm going to write a Windows 8.1 store app, which communicates with smart cards over ISO 7816-4/APDU commands. In the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK there is a class for such things [SmartCardConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardconnection.aspx) and its [TransmitAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardconnection.transmitasync.aspx) method. It is supported only by the phone platform right now. OK. 
But now I'm wondering: is it a way to send some APDUs in Windows Store App?